# Cannot prove $T_m(x,y)\leq T_m(x,z)$.

Tags: normed-spaces

Given
$$T_m(x,y)=\min(x,y),$$
for all $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Prove if $y\leq z$ then $T_m(x,y)\leq T_m(x,z)$, for all $x,y,z\in[0,1]$.

Given,
        \begin{align*}
  T_m(x,y)&=\min(x,y).
  \end{align*}
        For first cases $x\leq y$,
        \begin{align*}
  T_m(x,y)&=x.
  \end{align*}
        Given that $x\leq y$ and $y\leq z$, so $x\leq z$.
        We have
        \begin{align*}
  T_m(x,y)&\leq z\\
  \end{align*}
        For second cases $x>y$,
        \begin{align*}
  T_m(x,y)&=y\\
&\leq z
  \end{align*}

Now I cannot make form
$T_m(x,y)\leq T_m(x,z)$, so how to prove it?

Comment: In the second case you could consider two  subcases. If 1) $z\leq x$ you get $T_m(x,y)=y\leq z=T_m(x,z)$. If 2) $x<z$ you get $T_m(x,y)=y<x=T_m(x,z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\leq y$ then $T_m(x,y)=x$ and also $T_m(x,z)=x$ since $y\leq z\iff x\leq z$. Hence $T_m(x,y)=T_m(x,z)$ and the condition is satisfied

If $x>y$, we don't know for sure if $x\leq z$ or $x>z$

Supposing $y<x\leq z$, we have $T_m(x,y)=y<x=T_m(x,z)$ so this is satisfied.

Else, supposing $y\leq z<x$, we have $T_m(x,y)=y\leq z=T_m(x,z)$ so this too is satisfied.